# How to force a div to top/bottom of viewport while not taking it out of document flow?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-position

I'm wondering how I can make the blue div 'stick' to the top and bottom of the page (so you can't scroll beyond it) without breaking the document flow (I don't want it to overlap the content div). A crude version is here in the code snippet. If I set 'absolute' on it, it breaks flow and the content goes *under* the menu. If I leave it relative, you can scroll *beyond* it (I want it to stay at top: 0, bottom: 0 for a full 100vh with its own scrolling).

Is there something that I'm missing?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  
}

.sideNav {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.sidePanel {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 200vh;
  margin: auto;
  width: auto;
  border: 5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="sideNav">Side Nav</div>
  <div class="content">This is the content area</div>
  <div class="sidePanel">Side Panel</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You really can't do it without removing it from the document flow.

But if you know the width of the side panel, you can apply it as a right margin to the content div.

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.sideNav {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.sidePanel {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  position: fixed;  /* new */
  right: 0; /* new */
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 200vh;
  margin: auto;
  width: auto;
  border: 5px solid green;
  margin-right: 50px;  /* new */
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="sideNav">Side Nav</div>
  <div class="content">This is the content area</div>
  <div class="sidePanel">Side Panel</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is the panel expands/collapses, so I'm not sure how to get the width to match the animation. I was worried that I wouldn't be able to do it this way. Dang it.

Comment: Is it silly to set the onEnter and onExit methods of the `Collapse` Component with MUI? Maybe set a `child` div that stretches to 100vh with the parent container still 'visible' throughout? Does that make sense?